# time sheet overtime hours add up

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

This is basically about overtime calculations, but I want it calculated separately.    IF(A1>8,A1-8,0)

I want A1 when it reaches 8, to flow over to I1. Now I know this formula...
But additionally I would also like B1, C1, and D1 to do the same. So what I'm saying is that each of those cells when a value above 8 is input, I would like it to flow into I1 aswell. That's one part of it, also I would like any amount that is input to cells E1, F1, and G1 to flow into I1 . The final 3 cells are basically weekend work and considered by my company as overtime.

=SUMPRODUCT((A11:G11>H3:N3)*(A11:G11-H3:N3))
So this one works guys but, what I want to do is grab from two separate rows for the seven days of the week. Like this.....

=SUMPRODUCT((D11:G11,A13:C13>H3:N3)*(D11:G11,A13:C13-H3:N3))
But what I'm getting now is #VALUE!                                                                             I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
I would like to know if this is possible and will greatly appreciate the help solving this problem.

Comment: in other word , you want to convert hours to days , common you make it seems so complicated

Comment: Please include what you have tried and explain what isn't working.See  [Ask] and [MCVE] for guidance on posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Seeming no one answered you guys decided to minus my rep, I stumbled on the answer myself. I worked this out by making a table with each day and the hours of single time in them.

For the purpose of this formula below I'll say K3 is Sunday and that D19 is also the hours worked on the Sunday. It tells the cell to compare the number input to D19 and if greater than, then minus what is in K3 and return the value in the cell I have input the formula. Because this is for overtime I wanted it to add up each day separately and give me a running total through the week.  This Formula worked perfectly for me.

=SUM((D19>$K$3)*(D19-$K$3),(O11>$L$3)*(O11-$L$3),(P11>$M$3)*(P11-$M$3),(Q11>$N$3)*(Q11-$N$3),(K13>$H$3)*(K13-$H$3),(L13>$I$3)*(L13-$I$3),(M13>$J$3)*(M13-$J$3))

Feel free to copy and paste and change it to suit your needs.